# Terminology for creating an ID using the position in a graph? (adjacency data)

Tags: hash, graph

Is there a term for the process of creating an ID, based on connectivity information, that helps identify elements as matching based on their neighbors?

This can be as simple as looping over items in an array and accumulating next and previous items (possibly with bit-shifting, xor... etc).

Another example is using an order independent hash based on nodes connected by edges in a graph.

I've used this multiple times, but don't know if there is a term for it.

---

Typically the following steps are done by assigning an ID to each element
(often a number - created by hashing the contents).

Then iterate:

- Store a copy of all ID's to prevent reading modified values.
- Loop over each element and create a new ID from its value combined with the connected elements.

Each iteration the range of influence elements have on each-other increases - following a [triangle number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) sequence.

---

- Is there a term for each iteration?
- Is there a term for this entire process?